# Multidimensional dictionaries possible in Swift?

Tags: swift

Just learning Swift, coming from PHP. I'm trying to figure out if you can do deeply nested arrays in Swift. Here's a PHP example of what I'm talking about:

```
$myArray = array(

"motorcycles" => array ("Honda", "Ducati", "Yamaha"),
"cars" => array(
                "sedans" => array("Jetta", "Taurus", "Impala"),
                "sport" => array("Porsche", "Ferarri", "Corvette"),
                "trucks" => array (
                                "shortbed" => array("Ford F150", "Dodge Ram 1500"),
                                "longbed" => array(
                                                    "standardCab" => array("Ford F350", "Dodge Ram 2500"),
                                                    "crewCab" => array("Ford F350", "Dodge Ram 2500")
                                                    )
                            )
            )

);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in Swift that would be:

```
let myArray = [
    "motorcycles": ["Honda", "Ducati", "Yamaha"],
    "cars": [
        "sedans": ["Jetta", "Taurus", "Impala"],
        "sport" : ["Porsche", "Ferarri", "Corvette"],
        "trucks" : [
            "shortbed" : ["Ford F150", "Dodge Ram 1500"],
            "longbed" : [
                "standardCab":["Ford F350", "Dodge Ram 2500"],
                "crewCab":["Ford F350", "Dodge Ram 2500"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Reading values from such a structure can be a bit difficult though, since Swift has difficulty discerning the types.  To get the `standardCab` vehicles, you can do:

```
if let trucks = myArray["cars"]?["trucks"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let standardCab = trucks["longbed"]?["standardCab"] as? [String] {
        println(standardCab)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error when I use your example: "Playground execution failed". Seems like it should work, though, based on the examples I've been able to find online.

Comment: It worked for me with Xcode 6.1. Which version of Xcode are you running? Try adding a type to `myArray` to help the compiler along:  `let myArray:[String:AnyObject] = [`

Comment: Ah, that was it. Apparently my version of 6.1 had a bug. I grabbed the latest build and it works. Thanks!